# Running Javadoc and Sonar in Hudson

Tags: hudson

?I am trying to run SOnar and Javadoc together using Maven3. However it seems that both of them call a clean gaol before running javadoc:javadoc and sonar:sonar. Due to this the output of one of them is lost. My pom entries are

```
<build>

            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
              <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
</build> 

<reporting>
<plugins>
         <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <threshold>Low</threshold>
        <effort>Max</effort>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</reporting>
```

Is there anything wrong with my maven entries. Can someone clarify how can I run both the goals to gether.